# Updating a struct with reflect

Tags: go

I want to make my code shorter and I'm trying to understand how reflect works. The code below works (the real code has many more structs and are much longer). So shortly the function processInput gets string data from a TCP connection and it is used to populate the Hyperdeck struct.

```
type configuration struct {
        videoInput         string `cmd:"video input:"`
        audioMapping       int64  `cmd:"audio mapping:"`
        genlockInputResync bool   `cmd:"genlock input resync:"`
    }
    
type Hyperdeck struct {
    configuration  configuration
}

func (hd *Hyperdeck) processInput(s string) {
    switch hd.multilineCmd {
    case "configuration":
        if s != "\r\n" {
            if strings.HasPrefix(s, "video input:") {
                hd.configuration.videoInput = strings.TrimSpace(s[strings.Index(s, ":")+1 : len(s)-1])
            } else if strings.HasPrefix(s, "audio mapping:") {
                hd.configuration.audioMapping = stringToInt(strings.TrimSpace(s[strings.Index(s, ":")+1:len(s)-1]), hd)
            } else if strings.HasPrefix(s, "genlock input resync:") {
                hd.configuration.genlockInputResync = stringToBool(strings.TrimSpace(s[strings.Index(s, ":")+1:len(s)-1]), hd)
            }
        } else {
            hd.multilineCmd = ""
        }
    }

    switch {
    case strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(s), "configuration"):
        hd.multilineCmd = "configuration"
    }
}
```

I was thinking of making something like this that loops the stuct and identifies the type but I can't figure out how to update the struct. I've read and tried things from multiple websites but I just can't get it right.

```
func (hd *Hyperdeck) processInput(s string) {
        switch hd.multilineCmd {
        case "configuration":
            if s != "\r\n" {
                v := reflect.ValueOf(hd.configuration)
                t := v.Type()
                for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
                    if strings.HasPrefix(s, t.Field(i).Tag.Get("cmd")) {
                        if t.Field(i).Type.String() == "string" {
                            // UPDATE hd.configuration.videoInput
                        } else if t.Field(i).Type.String() == "int" {
                            //UPDATE hd.configuration.audioMapping
                        } else if t.Field(i).Type.String() == "bool" {
                            //UPDATE hd.configuration.genlockInputResync
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                hd.multilineCmd = ""
            }
        }
    
        switch {
        case strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(s), "configuration"):
            hd.multilineCmd = "configuration"
        }
    }
```

I think this code is usable for strings but can't figure out how to address it...

```
...FieldByName(types.Field(i).Name).SetString(strings.TrimSpace(s[strings.Index(s, ":")+1 : len(s)-1]))
```

And maybe the most important question, should I do it with reflect or leave it as it is now?

Comment: You can't update unexported struct fields with reflection.

Comment: Note that matching types against strings rather than types or kinds is poor style, and matching fields by type rather than by name is even poorer.